# Spring batch get read item in onSkipInWrite

Tags: java, spring-batch

Very simple use case but can't find a good solution.

- Reader: Reads records (entities) from the database (`HibernateCursorItemReader`)
- Processor: Maps entity records to Xml Beans (JaxB) based on a CLOB field that contains XML
- Writer: Writes the item to a file

In `onSkipInWrite` I need access to the originally read entity, in order to update its state (i.e. error state).
The generated XML isn't useful in this regard.

Can't seem to find a solid solution to the problem; how to get a reference to the read entity?

Answer (score 0):

By lack of better solution, I have updated the written xsd object to add a field annotated with `@XmlTransient`.
This prevents the `Jaxb2Marshaller` used by `StaxEventItemWriter` from including the field in the XML.
The annox plugin can be used in combination with xjc to declare the annotation through the bindings file (xPath).

This IMO is not a good solution, but it does work.
First, because it mixes the data from the read model into the written model (which it should not), and second because it requires to fetch the entity again before updating and persisting its state.

Other answers on SO I looked up dance around the problem, but there doesn't appear to be a straightforward solution to get a reference (AFAICS), if not for passing it through the execution context, which would force you to change the batch size to 1 which is not desirable.
Any callbacks pass only the written item, not the originally read object.